# BigQuery data load - Is it possible to collect error record?

Tags: google-bigquery

I could see the option "Number of errors allowed" to ignore bad records when running a job.

bq command line parameter:

```
--max_bad_records
```

Web interface:

[image: BigQuery-UI]

Is there way to collect the bad records that are rejected while executing the job?

Comment: As far as I know no such feature exists in bigquery, but I believe it could be a good feature request

Answer (score 1):

There currently is not a way but I agree with the other commenter that it would be a good feature request. Even exposing a sampling of bad records could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, this option is used only to skip bad records in the file and allows load job to succeed.

Answer (score -1):

May be it's collecting in [Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) page in GCP. Did you look here?